# error while enabling mod_rewrite module in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I am newbie in php. I'm doing project in codeignitor. i'm trying to enable **mod_rewrite** module in WAMP apache server but it shows me yellow triangle mark with exclamatory mark in it. I am not able to enable it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an apache/wamp question, not PHP.

Comment: Remove # from line LoadModule rewrite_module... in C:\wamp\bin\Apache\conf\httpd.conf and restart WAMP

Comment: Look in the Error Log for Apache, and if that tell you nothing, look in the Windows Event Viewer for error mesages from Apache

Comment: Thanks every one who helped me.